# Find the first N elements shared between two vectors of correlation scores

Tags: r, data-structures, statistics

I have two data tables, train and target, consisting of samples in rows and chemicals in columns, with the table values being the relative abundances of the chemicals in the samples. The chemicals are identical between the two data sets. I have found the absolute values of the Spearman correlations between the values in the training data and the target data, and now *I would like to find the smallest **i** such that the first **i** elements of both arrays contain **n** elements in common.*

Example: Let's say we're looking at chemical Y1 and the correlation values for train and target against chemicals Y1 through Y10 are:

```
     train
     Y1  Y2  Y3  Y4  Y5  Y6  Y7  Y8  Y9  Y10
Y1:   1  -1 -.2  .5 -.9  .7  .1  .1 -.2  -.5

     target
     Y1  Y2  Y3  Y4  Y5  Y6  Y7  Y8  Y9  Y10
Y1:   1  .1  .2  -.7 .6  .4  .2  .5 -.5  -.2
```

The rank ordering for the absolute values of each would be:

```
     train
Y1:  Y1  Y2  Y5  Y6  Y4  Y10 Y9  Y3  Y7  Y8  
     target
Y1:  Y1  Y4  Y5  Y8  Y9  Y6  Y3  Y7  Y10 Y2
```

Then the first 5 shared elements between train and target are:

```
Y1:  Y1, Y5, Y4, Y6, Y9
```

So for n = 5, the first 7 elements of both arrays have Y1, Y5, Y4, Y6, and Y9 in common. And the algorithm comparing them would have to go out to the 7th element to find 5 that were in both lists. Worst case, it would have to go out to the 10th element.

Here's what I've tried:

- Rank-ordering the list of absolute correlations for each chemical for train and target, taking the intersection of the two lists, and taking the first N elements of the result. Fails because the chemicals are identical for train and target, so the intersection is just the whole list of chemicals, and the ordering of the result is determined solely by whether train or target is the first argument to intersect()
- Going one chemical at a time, taking the intersection of the first N correlation scores for train and target, checking whether the length of the intersection is less than N, and if so, taking the intersection of the first N+1 scores, repeat until the intersection is N long. Accurate, but assuming set intersection is O(n), this would be an O(n^2) algorithm. I'd like to do better. Current R code below:

  ```
      common = c()
      num = 10
      i = num
      while(length(common)<(num)){
          common = intersect(corr_train[2:(i+1)], corr_target[2:(i+1)])
          i = i + 1
      }
  ```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the difference of characteristics of `abs(trainY2-tragetY2)` and Y6 such that Y2 wouldn't be on the resulting vector?

Comment: What made you choose Y9 over Y2 in your list of the 5 first shared elements? If you sum the order of each Y between the 2 sorted set, you could then choose the elements having the 5 smallest values to have your final list (2, 6, 7, 10, 12 in your example). This would be a O(n + log(n)) complexity.

Comment: @marcguery Oops. I phrased the question wrong. I should have said "Find the smallest i such that the first i elements of both arrays contain n elements in common." So for n = 5, the first 7 elements of both arrays have Y1, Y5, Y4, Y6, and Y9 in common. Sorry for the confusion; I'll edit the question.

Comment: If, in all cases, Y1=1, you're just complicating your going forward selection by leaving it in. You might further clarify smallest net `i`, such that it results in the above comment order if smallest is the desired, which would result in Y1, Y9, Y6, Y4, Y5... after concatenating Y1 back in. Though on the present logic, poor Y2.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow "You might further clarify smallest net i, such that it results in the above comment order if smallest is the desired, which would result in Y1, Y9, Y6, Y4, Y5... after concatenating Y1 back in." But you're right about dropping Y1, which is identically 1 (that's what the current code does; I just wanted to keep the example simple).

Comment: In this case simplifying didn't. And, as the above series of queries suggests, you haven't really thought through, and then expressed what you want. You kill rank by leaving Y1 in, in the example, and then don't really make a decision of inclusion against these assays, as the repeated requests for explication of Y2 vs Y6 or Y2 vs Y9 suggest.  How might we corner you into deciding what you want?

Comment: Not sure whether you saw it, but I rephrased the summary of the question to read: "Find the smallest i such that the first i elements of both arrays contain n elements in common." In the example above, the result is that i=7 when n=5 (i.e. you have to take the first seven elements of both arrays to get five elements in common). I'll add a step-by-step description of the current logic if it helps clarify things. The inclusion or exclusion of Y1 wouldn't make any difference to the algorithm for determining i; you would just start on the 2nd element instead of the 1st. Convince me otherwise.

Comment: @Chris just added the original R code to the question. I'm reverse-engineering the purpose of someone else's code by looking at what it does (which hopefully explains some of the lack of clarity on my part).

Comment: Understood, and in the context, something like trying to discern the hidden Markov(OP) prior [not your's]. And no argument nor need of convincing on your above. But still fishing for 'stability' in the `rank` call relative to @marcguery approach below to arrive at his Raw Data, which till now I can't get Y3 & Y9 to swap order. And it may be that only one (train or target) need a ties.method and not both...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This algorithm will build the set containing *n* common elements using the *i* smallest ranked elements from 2 sets 'train' and 'target' of equal size *m* with a complexity of the order of *O(log(m)+m)*.

Basically, a score equal to the rank of each element in each ordered set is calculated and compared between the corresponding elements. The idea is to add an element to the common list only if the corresponding element from the other list is not ranked higher.

When the same *i* would be obtained from adding different elements of the 2 sets (for instance, when `n = 7`, Y7 or Y10 could be chosen), the 'train' set would be arbitrarily favored.

```
#Calculate the rank of each element in each set
trainrank <- rank(train)
targetrank <- rank(target)

#Sort both sets and attribute each element their rank
trainscores <- order(trainrank)
targetscores <- order(targetrank)

#Include elements of the train set if their ranking is
# superior or equal to those of the target set
includetrain <- trainscores>=targetscores
includetrain <- includetrain[trainrank]

#Include elements of the target set if their ranking is
# strictly superior to those of the train set
includetarget <- targetscores>trainscores
includetarget <- includetarget[targetrank]

#To get a set containing n common elements 
# from 2 sets of equal size m,
# this code will take 2*m operations at most
commonset <- c()
m = length(train)
n = 5

i = 1
while (length(commonset) < n){
  newelement <- NA
  while(i <= m & is.na(newelement)){
    #If the selection of train or target elements
    # gave the same i first elements,
    # this would favor the train element
    if(includetrain[i]){
      newelement <- train[i]
      includetrain[i] <- FALSE
    }
    else if (includetarget[i]){
      newelement <- target[i]
      includetarget[i] <- FALSE
    }
    else{
      i = i+1 #Next element if both are false
    }
  }
    commonset <- c(commonset, newelement)
}
commonset #Common set of n elements
# "Y1" "Y5" "Y4" "Y6" "Y9"
print(i) #First i elements used to build the common set
# 7
```

---

**Raw data**

```
#Train and target data sets
train <- c("Y1","Y2","Y5","Y6","Y4","Y10","Y9","Y3","Y7","Y8")
target <- c("Y1","Y4","Y5","Y8","Y9","Y6","Y3","Y7","Y10","Y2")
```

Comment: I like your approach here, though specifying a desirable `ties.method` to `rank` avoids my `names(commonset)
[1] "y1" "y3" "y4" "y6" "y7"`, I think, arrived at twice in new env(s). In this instance it looks like `ties.method = 'first'` would serve...but still somewhat fishing for OP's final logic.

Comment: In any case, some words about arriving at Raw Data values would seem in order.

Comment: Raw data values are the one provided by the OP. Nowhere did the OP asked for a way to order his correlation values.

Comment: @Chris, the raw data values **marcguery** used are the rank ordering for the absolute values of the correlation scores for chemical Y1 with chemicals Y1 through Y10. The first code box in my question has the numerical correlation scores; the second one is the ranking of the chemicals.

Comment: `sort(rank(abs(target)), decreasing = TRUE)` is well behaved, just saying, for me, `sort(rank(abs(train)), decreasing = TRUE)` remains slippery even as not asked for, in as much as it can cloud results.